# Open a web page with header values in Angular 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-web-api, angular6, angular4-httpclient

Background: We have two legacy ASP.NET MVC websites and both websites talk to each other.In one of the cases we are redirecting the user from one application to another, in this case the application W1 sends all the authentication details to application W2, W2 gets all the authentication details and proceeds further in the application flow.

Problem: Now the application W1 is being migrated to Angular 6 and web api.
But application W2 is still on ASP.Net MVC(web forms). Now I want to open(in new tab) a page in W2 by passing all the authentication details from my angular 6 SPA.

I did look at multiple blogs to find solution but could not succeed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: not sure what the issue is, you can still use redirect with angular, right?

Comment: How to pass few values in the header and make http call to open the page in the new tab?

Comment: How about you show us some code so that we can help?